# How to compare the topical similarity between two documents in Python Gensim from their topic distributions?

Tags: python, gensim, lda

I have trained a LDA model on a corpus using Gensim. Now that I have the topic distribution for each document, how can I compare how similar two documents are in topics? I would like to have a summary measure. For example, the following are the topic distributions of two documents. There are totally 75 topics. For brevity, I show only the first 10 topics with largest probabilities (so the topics are not in order). (40, 0.5523168) means that topic #40 has a probability of 0.5523168 for DOC #1. Should I calculate the Euclidean or Cosine distance between the two vectors? And using this summary measure, can I say that, for example, DOC 1 is more similar to DOC2 than to DOC3, or DOC1 and DOC 2 are more similar to each other than DOC 3 and DOC 4 topically? Thank you!

```
DOC #1:
[(40, 0.5523168), (60, 0.12225048), (43, 0.07556598), (41, 0.065885976), 
(22, 0.05838573), (24, 0.044774733), (74, 0.019839266), (65, 0.019544959), 
(51, 0.015470431), (36, 0.013449047)]


DOC #2:
[(73, 0.58864516), (41, 0.16827711), (51, 0.09783472), (63, 0.06510383), 
(24, 0.04722658), (32, 0.014467965), (44, 0.012267662), (47, 0.0031533625), 
(18, 0.0022214972), (0, 1.2154361e-05)]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Gensim Functionality**

Gensim provides the `similarities.docsim` functionality - to "compute similarities across a collection of documents in the Vector Space Model." You can see the [documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/similarities/docsim.html) here, there is also a [tutorial](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/Similarity_Queries.ipynb) here for the similarity queries.

**Document Similarity Measures**

Using euclidian distances would be an uncommon choice - you could, but there are potential issues. You could use cosine similarity [(link to python tutorial)](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/) - this takes the cosine of the angle of two document vectors, which has the advantage of being easily understood (1= the documents are perfectly alike, to -1=the documents have no similarity at all) and yes, you can compare the cosine similarity of documents 1 & 2 and compare it to that of documents 3 & 4, or calculate the similarity values of doc1 to doc2 and doc1 and doc3 and compare them. There is a pretty [good tutorial here.](https://www.machinelearningplus.com/nlp/cosine-similarity/)

You might also find my answer to [this question over at CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/402633/measuring-similarity-between-document-and-category/402653#402653) informative, even though your question is somewhat different.

Gensim also has other [distance metrics](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/docs/notebooks/distance_metrics.ipynb) available. These are pretty much all included in gensim's `matutils`.

**Topical distances**

You can also measure distances between *topics* using (some) of these distances in the above link, such as Hellinger distance.